Is it possible to present a NavigationStack view from inside a sheet?
Many popular apps have the ability to navigate to a new view from a sheet. For example, in the comment sheets in Instagram and TikTok, pressing on the commenting user's icon pushes in a whole new view for the user's profile. Once that view is dismissed, it returns to the previous view, where the comments sheet is still open.
However, when I have a .navigationDestination outside of the sheet, it does navigate but the sheet remains in place, on top of the views:
.sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
    VStack {
        Button("Present new view") {
            presentDestination = true
        }
    }
}
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $presentDestination) {
    VStack {
        Text("New view")
    }
}

Alternatively if I place the navigationDestination inside the view presented by .sheet, this results in navigation only within the sheet. I would want the whole screen be replaced with the new screen, as usually happens.
Is this not possible with Apple's built-in sheet?

The sheet needs a Stack too or use a navigation path

You could try this approach using a NavigationStack(path: $path) and
dismiss() to navigate to a new page of the root view from action/selection
in the sheet.
Example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentSheet = false
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            Text("ContentView")
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                presentSheet = true
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { page in
                if page == "Page1" {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Page1 view")
                    }
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Page2 view")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet) {
            SheetView(path: $path)
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("SheetView")
            Button("Present Page1 view") {
                path.append("Page1")
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for helping out! This indeed does show Page2 view without the sheet. However it also animates the sheet dismissal and once navigating back from Page2 to Page1, the sheet is obviously not there anymore, which is a bit problematic in the UI I'm working on. Shame that many of the built-in blocks of SwiftUI are still rather limited/opinionated.

This answer suggests wrapping dismiss() in a withAnimation(nil) closure. I haven't tried it myself. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78693351/719690

@lndbrg - Did you find anything for this? I am also looking for it's solution. I looked at many github repos which has swiftui routing, but it doesn't working for navigation within the sheet.
